# Is there a kubectl port-forward equivalent in podman?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, portforwarding, podman

There are TCP ports that should not be exposed to the outside world, but are isolated between several containers in a network.

To access such a port for debugging purposes, `kubectl port-forward` can be used from outside the container network. E.g. for access to a non-exposed k8s database on a developer workstation: `kubectl port-forward pods / app-dev-database-0 5432: 5432 -n app`

**Is there a Podman equivalent for `kubectl port-forward` to set up port forwarding from the Podman host to an existing and running container?**

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use [norouter](https://norouter.io/docs/getting-started/) for your use case?

Comment: I feel like you're comparing apples to oranges, since (AFAIK) there is no such equivalent in `docker` of what you are describing, and thus kubectl is uniquely positioned to do post-facto port forwarding in ways both docker and podman are not. FWIW, even the kubernetes mechanism is implemented via `socat` on the Node, so it may be worth examining how that is implemented if you are trying to reinvent that process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think podman has such an option. There is a 'network' option available in podman. However, it is for creating container networks and not the purpose of port forwarding.

To answer your question, I think socat is the only option

```
# socat TCP4-LISTEN:5431 TCP4:10.89.1.10:5432
```

Here anyone connects to 5431 port of the server will be redirected to a container IP and port 10.89.1.10:5432

Comment: Yes I also thought about just using socat. Simple an neat solution. One improvement could be using the container name instead of the IP since it is auto assigned.

`socat TCP4-LISTEN:5431 TCP4:$(podman inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name):5432`

Comment: @SimonSchürg that is a very useful way to use socat with podman. thanks.